# Bound Excel Table (ListObject) formula not calculating

Tags: excel, data-binding, datatable, vsto, listobject

On a DataTable bound to an Excel ListObject, if you insert formula into columns like this..

```
listObject.DataSource = bindDataTable;

listObject.ListColumns[COLUMN_NAME].DataBodyRange.FormulaLocal = "=YOUR_FORMULA"
```

Formulas aren't '*sticking*'.  They just resolve the value. Any changes that should affect the value, aren't updating the field.

Turning off calculation, same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign YOUR_FORMULA to the ***Expression*** property of the **DataTable** instead:

```
dataTable.Columns[COLUMN_NAME].Expression = "=YOUR_FORMULA"
```